# ValueError: scheme https is invalid in websocket client to say hello

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, clientwebsocket

I get similar problem as this question [websockets "scheme https is invalid", but i'm actually trying to use https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997384/websockets-scheme-https-is-invalid-but-im-actually-trying-to-use-https)
The problem is that I received an instruction of connecting for getting data from a server and in that document, he gave me the list of servers to connect.
Unfortunately, it is a list of https://theirserverurl.com instead of wss:// as usual.
I tried to say hello to one of such servers by:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("https://theirserverurl.com")
print ("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print ("Sent")
print ("Reeiving...")
result =  ws.recv()
print ("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()
```

And I got the error that:

```
ValueError: scheme https is invalid
```

Is there any solution to overcome this stack on python.
Pls, help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is incorrect. You should enter the WSS URL like this:

```
wss://live-ws-pg-group3.kuaishou.com/websocket
```